# Deleting Data also increasing Size of Table

Tags: sql-server-2008

Table Size: 500GB 2Days Ago (Approx)
Index Size: Clustered Index Not Avbailable
Non clustered 180GB in size 2 Days Ago before starting of the delete process
Row Count: 9 Billion Rows 2 Days Ago (Approx)

Scheduled a job to delete the data from the table in chunks of 1Million. The job has deleted over 0.5Million rows.

Table Size now: 510 GB 
Index Size: 220GB 
Row Count: 8.1Billion

Deleting rows from Huge table increased the index size.
There is no fragmentation on my Index either.

Need suggestions on what to do.

Comment: What does this query return?  `SELECT name, type_desc, fill_factor
FROM sys.indexes
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.YourTable');`

Comment: Retunrs name type_desc fill_factor
NULL HEAP 0
IX_ClNoRefQNo NONCLUSTERED 0

Comment: Fill Factor 0 in Heap and Nonclustered Index

Comment: Space won't be reclaimed until pages are empty so I'm guessing your delete query is selective, leaving rows in each page. The table and index will grow if you are also inserting into this table. Execute `ALTER TABLE YourSchema.YourTable REBUILD;` to reclaim space.

Comment: Also, I would expect the index to grow only in this case only if the index key is incremental. With a random key, the space within each index page would have been reused.

Comment: Why no clustered index?